# Emacs and OS X Menu Bar

Tags: osx, menu-bar

Been looking for a solution to this for a while now. On OS X minors mode fill the menu bar with useless menu items. Here's a screenshot:

[image: menubar](![minor modes taken over the menu bar]

If you can't tell, Emacs menu items are blocking the rest of my menu bar. Is there a way to tell Emacs to not use the menu bar?

I'm using [this port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port) of emacs.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly.  Do you want to disable the menu bar entirely, or do you just want to remove individual top-level items?

Comment: According to other answers, it's not possible to remove the menu bar entirely, so now I'm looking for a way to remove individual items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't hide the menu bar on OS X from within Emacs.  It's always shown for non-fullscreen applications, that's simply how OS X works.  Applications have no influence on that.

## No menu bar

If you'd like to use Emacs without any menu bar, enable fullscreen mode with `M-x toggle-frame-fullscreen`.

## Removing individual items

If you'd just like to remove individual items from the menu bar, adjust the corresponding key maps in your `init.el`.  For instance, the following snippet removes the “Options”, “Edit” and ”Tools” menus:

```
(define-key global-map [menu-bar options] nil)
(define-key global-map [menu-bar edit] nil)
(define-key global-map [menu-bar tools] nil)
```

A [mailing list post from Xah Lee](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-02/msg00058.html) has more examples.

Comment: Awesome! This works for menus added by `(define-key global-map [menu-bar...` but doesn't work for items added using other packages like `easymenu`, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: @AmmarAbdulaziz Well, remove the `menu-bar` binding from the corresponding key map.  The details depend on where and how the menu is defined.  In doubt, read the source.